# Hamiltonian paths and cycles of rook graph on $n\times2$ chessboard

Tags: graph-theory, closed-form, hamiltonian-path, chessboard

According to OEIS, there are closed form for directed Hamiltonian paths ([A096121](http://oeis.org/A096121)) and Hamiltonian cycles ([A276356](http://oeis.org/A276356)) of rook graph on $n\times2$ chessboard. Are there papers which include proof of those closed forms? Are there closed forms for $n\times m$ ([A269565](http://oeis.org/A269565), [A269562](http://oeis.org/A269562)) with $m>2$?

Comment: At least for http://oeis.org/A276356, the comments on the OEIS sequence appear to contain a proof.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, thank you for comment! Given proof is not clear to me.